# Handling selections across multipe XAML User control

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have multiple user controls in my page. Initially I set the border thickness to zero for all the user controls.

When the user selects a particular control instance through mouse or touch events, I want the border to be shown with specific thickness.

Later when the mouse moves out of the control or when the user selects another control instance I want the border to be shown for this newly selected control and reset the border thickness to zero for the previously selected control.

How can I achieve this in XAML?

Comment: Setting the border thickness in OnPointerEntered to specific value and then resetting to zero in OnPointerExited worked. But when the mouse pointer is over one user control instance and on tapping another I need the selection to change.

Comment: How is your UserControl looks like and how they should be laid out on the page? Can't you use something like GridView or ListView in this case?

Comment: You can either do what @kimsk suggested (which will basically do this for you) or you can use Visual States to change the border thickness. All controls should already have 4 'Common States' which includes 'PointedOver'. You can then add ones for Selected, SelectedPointedOver, etc. ListView and GridView already include these VisualStates.